# What does the -E in sudo -E do?

Tags: linux

I'm following the instructions in a tutorial and they say to do `sudo -E foo`. I cannot find what the -E does through a google search. What does it do and how I could have found that out without asking this question?

Comment: I asked exactly same question here few months ago https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/407697/255251

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check the manual: `man sudo`

> **-E** - The **-E** (*preserve environment*) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the **-E** option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

There's also [ExplainShell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sudo+-E+foo) that tries to explain commands with `man` pages.

Answer (score 6):

#### How I could have found that out without asking this question?

Search the [Linux manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/) or type `man sudo` in a Linux shell.

---

#### What does it do?

> The `-E` (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy
>   that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.
>   The security policy may return an error if the `-E` option is specified
>   and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Source [Sudo Manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html)